# spring data mongodb 1.8.x - GridFS collection name in XML

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, gridfs

is possible modify collection name of gridfs target in configuration XML? Default name is "fs.files"

this is a configuration file:

```
    <mongo:repositories base-package="it.marcoberri.repositories" />

    <mongo:mongo host="${mongo.db.server}" port="${mongo.db.port}" />

    <mongo:db-factory dbname="${mongo.db.name}" mongo-ref="mongo"
        id="mongoDbFactory" />

    <mongo:mapping-converter id="converter" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.gridfs.GridFsTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
        <constructor-arg ref="converter" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongo" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="${mongo.db.name}" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this line

```
<constructor-arg name="bucket" value="xxx" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
  <bean class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.gridfs.GridFsTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
        <constructor-arg ref="converter" />
        <constructor-arg name="bucket" value="NameOsTheFsCollection" />
  </bean>
```

If you have more than one collection of Gridfs type and want to have different names for each one, you must declare one GridFsTemplate for each, using this approach.